# Dynamic inventory for Ansible Controller on Google Cloud and nodes on EC2 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am trying to find out a way to create dynamic inventory in Ansible that can let me use the updated IP of EC2 instances after restart. I have tried to search in documentation but there is not much information available about it.

Any help around this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting up the access key details in **`ec2.ini (an inventory script setting for ec2.py)`**, I was getting the error as **`"ERROR: "Forbidden", while: getting ElastiCache clusters"`**.

**`Solution:`** I intially thought that it is because of Google cloud but enabling the **`"elasticache = False"`** option in **`ec2.ini`** resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is how to update your inventory on EC2

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#inventory-script-example-aws-ec2

For Google Cloud

https://devopscube.com/ansible-dymanic-inventry-google-cloud/

Comment: It is only when all the nodes are hosted on same platform, my query was if I have my Ansible Controller hosted in Google Cloud and all other Ansible Nodes are hosted in AWS EC2.

Comment: @AshishBansal: what makes you think it is not possible to use the AWS inventory script from a google machine ? Have you tried ? What are the problems you are facing ? The [inventory script heading](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.py) states: `Generates inventory that Ansible can understand by making API request to AWS EC2 using the Boto library.` So it should work from anywhere you can access the API.

Comment: @Zeitounator I tried but it wasn't working out, let me set that again and try. Looks, like I am messing up some config then.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of *ec2.py* script is deprecated and unmaintained. You have now to use the [aws_ec2](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html) inventory plugin.

Though this plugin only list ec2 instances (no more information on elasticache, rds...).